# How to solve $(2x+2, 6x) = x+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm looking at an old discrete mathematics test preparing for my test tomorrow and one question says solve for $x$ and gives the above.  I'm thinking that this is the $\gcd(2x+2, 6x)$ but have never seen this type of question before.

Comment: If it is $\gcd$, then it means $x+1\mathrel|6x$ which can only happen when $x+1\mathrel|6$.  How would you continue?

Comment: oh, thats right! x+1 | 6x and x+1 | 2x+2, which means x = 1, 2, 5. correct?

Comment: actually, why can x + 1 | 6x only when x+1 | 6???

Comment: $x+1$ and $x$ are coprime.  If $x+1$ divides a multiple of $x$ it means it has to divide the other factor.  Now: out of those three cases ($x=1,2,5$, we might add $x=0$), which will work and which won't work?

Comment: got it, only 1 and 5 will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gcd(2x+2,6x)=x+1$ it means that $\def\divides{\mathrel{|}}x+1\divides2x+2$ and $x+1\divides6x$ and there is no greater divisor.

It is trivial that for any $x$ then $x+1\divides2x+2$.

$\gcd(x,x+1)=1$, as $x$ and $x+1$ are coprimes, then if $x+1\divides kx$ then necessarily $x+1\divides k$.  Therefor if $x+1\divides6x$ then $x+1\divides6$.

$6$ has only four natural divisors: $1,2,3,6$, so the possible values of $x$ are $x=0,1,2,5$.  Replacing these values in the equation we have:

\begin{align}
x&=0:&\gcd(2,0)&=1&&\text{which is false} \\
x&=1:&\gcd(4,6)&=2&&\text{which is true} \\
x&=2:&\gcd(6,12)&=3&&\text{which is false} \\
x&=5:&\gcd(12,30)&=6&&\text{which is true}
\end{align}

Comment: sorry, but how do we know x and x+1 are coprime?

Comment: If $n$ divides both $x$ and $x+1$ then it divides their difference which is ...

Comment: If $d\divides a$ and $d\divides b$ with $a>b$, then $d\divides a-b$.  If $d\divides x+1$ and $d\divides x$ then $d\divides x+1-x=1$ which means that $d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You might consult GAP as follows:

```
gap> for i in [0..7] do if Gcd(2*i+2,6*i)=i+1 then Print(i,"\n"); else Print("*","\n"); fi; od;

> *
  1
  *
  *
  *
  5
  *
  *
```